# CSS defined in library is not included, but theme works

Tags: 8, theming

themes/custom/teleci/teleci.info.yml:

```
base theme: bartik
core: 8.x
name: Teleci
package: Custom
type: theme
version: "1.1"
libraries:
  - teleci/global-styling
```

themes/custom/teleci/teleci.libraries.yml:

```
global-styling:
  version: "1.1"
  css:
    theme:
      css/override.css: {}
      css/style.css: {}
```

I also have custom template in `themes\custom\teleci\templates\block--teleci-branding.html.twig` that is loading correctly - that means the theme works. But the CSS files are not included (they are not in the generated HTML).

I tried

- `php drupal.phar cr all`
- setting bartik as default and then set my theme back
- clear browser cache
- open in private window
- disable JS/CSS minification in settings
- check both yml files in yamllint.com
- disable base theme (bartik)

I'm out of ideas and would appreciate any help :(

**Update:** I created minimal theme (that does not work as well) for you to test. Could you please test it and let me know if it works for you? https://github.com/tomasfejfar/drupal-simple-theme/ (i have it in `/themes/custom`)

**Update 2:** the mini-theme works when I fixed a small bug that is not present in my theme. So there is something about my theme that makes it break.

Comment: Did you clear/flush the Drupal cache? If you are using drupal console, its suppose to be `drupal cr all`

Comment: yes, as noted in list of things I tried: ˙λ php drupal.phar cr all

 Rebuilding cache(s), wait a moment please.


 [OK] Done clearing cache(s).˙

Comment: I've never seen it used with `php` but ok.

Comment: any errors in the log or in the browser console?

Comment: Nothing in console, nor error log

Comment: Why the downvotes? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: I +1 u to make up for the those unjustified down votes. Maybe try without using a base theme (for testing purposes).

Comment: +1, I don't see the reason for having been downvoted. Did you check your YAML indentation to be sure it's accurate? It looks fine from here but perhaps double check that.

Comment: Did that first thing after seeing simmilar problems ("check both yml files in yamllint.com" in list) :(

Comment: Tried without base theme - the page is now unstyled. Although there are some imported styles in header:
`<style media="all">@import url("/<redacted>/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/ajax-progress.module.css?ocz13k");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it seems to have been fixed. **I re-created the same template again under a new name.** Checked the diff of `theme.info.yml` and `theme.libraries.yml` files - only difference is the name. The new template has all the same functionality the previous had and is 1-to-1 copy except for the name. So only thing I can think of is that while playing with the template something has broken and left some residue in the database that prevented the theme from functioning properly ever again.

Thanks everyone who tried to help!